# Using Fat arrow in node module module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am new to node modules. I tried

```
module.exports = function (firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.fullName = function () { 
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

then

let person1 = new person('Rajesh','Dhoundiyal')

This works. But when i try to use Fat arrow in module.exports it does not works.

e.g. `module.exports =  (firstName, lastName) => {`

This gives error later as `person is not a constructor`. I am unable to know why it happen. Can anyone please tell me why fat arrow not works here.

Comment: Arrow functions do not create their own `this`. The `this` scope in an Arrow function refers to a higher level scope. In other words, the `this` scope is as if there was no Arrow function there.

Comment: If you want to see the only difference between arrow functions and "regular" functions, just console.log(this).

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in `arrow-funciton` is not same with other normal function. The `this` in `arrow-funciton` is point to the **context** which the `arrow-funciton` be defined, so it can not be use as a **constructor**
Please refer to [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: So I cant use fat arrow in this case. right?

Comment: No you cant,the arrow-function is use to shorter functions and non-binding of this.